# GitHub MarkDown: Are Macros and Variables possible?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I've been learning github markdown, I had a question about variables and macros.

is it possible to define a variable or macro to prevent repeated printing of a block of text?

The use case is that I have a table producing a big grid of hyperlinks - the links look like the below.

```
http://www.a-big-long-big-big-long-hyperlink/more-long-stuff?id=1234
```

it would be nice if I could do something like the below once:

```
$link=http://www.a-big-long-big-big-long-hyperlink/more-long-stuff?id
```

and then in each cell in the table, I can say something like

```
$link=1234
```

Some other cell

```
$link=2345
```

the idea being that:

- The table (which has ~10 columns and ~10 rows) is a bit easier to see on a normal screen, at the moment with the prefix to the links being so long, it looks really ugly as the links wrap to the next line
- If I want to change the root link, I can change it in one place (yes, I know I could do search and replace in an editor!)

Cheers.

Answer (score 16):

Below are a few ways to write Reference-Links

```
[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.somewebsite.com)

[I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.somewebsite.com "somewebsite's Homepage")

[I'm a reference-style link][Arbitrary case-insensitive reference text]

[I'm a relative reference to a repository file](../blob/master/LICENSE)

[You can use numbers for reference-style link definitions][1]

Or leave it empty and use the [link text itself]

Some text to show that the reference links can follow later.

[arbitrary case-insensitive reference text]: https://www.somewebsite.org
[1]: http://somewebsite.org
[link text itself]: http://www.somewebsite.com
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Doesn't Op wish to define a variable, such as the root of a url and use that in many locations where he only supplies the part that changes (an ID).

Comment: Can the context of the text somehow make into the link? For example, `[FOO-11](JIRA)` expanding into `https://jira.example.net/browse/FOO-11` ?

Comment: @Gerry, it did help me.  I was trying to avoid re-typing `http://github.com/myrepo/...` and @Adi's suggestion was quite helpful here...Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a feature of Markdown called "Reference-style links".

`[link text][id]` or just `[link text]` if link-text is unique and consist only of letters, numbers, spaces and punctuation. They are not case sensitive.

then somewhere in the document you *define* what `id` is:

`[id]: http://example.com/whatever`

See 
https://github.com/biserkov/markdown-playground/blob/master/README.md and

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biserkov/markdown-playground/master/README.md

Comment: This is nice but not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in basic Markdown, but there are extensions that add macros and variables. ([Example](https://github.com/fossunited/markdown-macros).)

Answer (score -5):

GitHub Markdown (for .md files) has variables through `capture`:

```
{% capture nameOfVariableToCapture %}any markdown here...{% endcapture %}

{{ nameOfVariableToCapture }} -- that prints the content of the variable
```

or from `{% assign variableName = "text etc." %}`.

As a test, I created  https://github.com/SeLite/SeLite.github.io/blob/master/MarkdownTest.md. You can see its content at http://selite.github.io/MarkdownTest (ignore the header and footer, that comes from a framework).

Comment: @vaughan: Looks like it does not. An enigmatic answer indeed. "you could probably benefit from it" -- if only you could make it work :).

Comment: @vaughan
**GitHub Pages** uses **Jekyll** which understands the _template language_ **Liquid**.
This is that.

More on [Jekyll gh-pages](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/): https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

I also found a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606739/what-the-the-scope-of-liquid-variables-on-jekyll-on-github-pages) with examples about variables on GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606739/what-the-the-scope-of-liquid-variables-on-jekyll-on-github-pages

Comment: This is quite useful for Github Pages (and if your project is on github, it's not such a stretch) though it would be worth clarifying that it won't work for the inline display of markdown files on github itself. Eg for the README.md file. This is because markdown is a format not an executable language, I guess.

Comment: It looks like the original question asked specifically about github markdown, so this seems legit. Maybe I missed something...