# What the the scope of Liquid variables on Jekyll on GitHub Pages

Tags: variables, scope, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have created a simple Jekyll page (processed and hosted by GitHub Pages) with a Liquid counter variable where I loop through some data and dump it out and count the number of items with a given property.

For example:

```
Complete Before: {{ complete }}
{% for book in books %}
Title: {{book.Title}}
{% if book.Completed == "true" %}
{% increment completed %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
Complete After: {{ complete }}
```

Now I have the same chunk of code on two different pages, but the data in books is different it both cases, but the value of the variable `completed` looks like it's being saved across the processing of both pages which results in page one looking like

```
Complete Before:
Title: Foo
Title: Bar
Complete After: 2
```

and page two looks like

```
Complete Before: 2
Title: Baz
Complete After: 3
```

How can I get the completed variable to be unique per page without needing to change each page to use a different variable name.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. Do you have a repository url ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel - See the two markdown pages [in this repo](https://github.com/veleek/veleek.github.io/tree/master/Liquid) and the associated [pages rendered on GitHub pages here](http://www.veleek.com/Liquid/IncrementTest1).  As you can see these pages share no code, it's just an identically named variable but it's shared across both pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `assign` in this case and increment the variable with the `plus` filter. `increment` behaves a little different than one expects, it does not modify a common Jekyll variable value:

```
{% assign complete=0 %}
Complete Before: {{ complete }}
 {% for book in books %}
 Title: {{book.Title}}
 {% if book.Completed == "true" %}
 {% complete=complete | plus:'1'  %}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 Complete After: {{ complete }}
```

## Update

The problem relies in its scope, at least, that is not what I naturally expect, this is a simple example to show it:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit: 2%}
increment {{forloop.index}}
- before {{complete}}
- current increment: {% increment complete %}
- after {{complete}}

<hr>
{% endfor %}

New loop

{% for post in site.posts limit: 2%}
increment {{forloop.index}}
- before {{complete}}
- current increment: {% increment complete %}
- after {{complete}} EXPECTED: {{forloop.index}}

<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
increment 1

    before
    current increment: 0
    after 1

increment 2

    before 1
    current increment: 1
    after 2

New loop

increment 1

    before 2
    current increment: 2
    after 3 EXPECTED: 1

increment 2

    before 3
    current increment: 3
    after 4 EXPECTED: 2
```

Comment: Ahh, the `plus` filter.  I was trying to use complete = complete + 1 without any luck and didn't see the filter alternative.  Do you know where I can find any additional detail around `increment` behavior.  How SHOULD one expect increment to behave?  What's a common scenario where I would want to use increment?

Comment: I didn't have to use `increment`, I'm just comfortable using `assign` and filters allows me to have greater control over the variables, like how much to increment, etc. You can see some `increment` examples here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#increment

Comment: None of the examples there really explain why increment wouldn't behave the way I expect it to.  What did you mean when you said it does not modify a common Jekyll variable value.  Were you just referring to the fact that an increment variable is not the same as an assign'd variable value.  That wouldn't explain the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify but all you did was re-show what the original problem I was experiencing was.  I can see myself that increment is behaving differently.  I was hoping there was some documentation that explained WHY it was behaving differently and what to expect (e.g. Which page is counting going to start on? Is it only pages in the same directory?).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [liquid::increment code](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/tags/increment.rb), you can see how it works and where is the boundary between context `myvar` and local `myvar`.

note that context `myvar` is passed across all pages, posts. It's a "global" variable.

#### On first page :

`{% increment myvar %}` -> **output : 0**

- retrieve context `myvar`, assign 0 if it's `nil`
- store it in a temporary variable
- does a post increment (`myvar++`)
- stores the value (1) in the `myvar` context variable
- print temporary variable (0)

`{{ myvar }}` -> **output : 1**

As `myvar` is not assigned to a local variable, **this liquid tag is using the fallback value of the context variable `myvar`** but doesn't modify it.

#### On second page :

`{% assign myvar = 100 %}`

assign `100` to local `myvar` variable.

`{% increment myvar %}` -> output : 1

- retrieve context `myvar`, which is 1
- store it in a temporary variable
- does a post increment (`myvar++`)
- stores the value (2) in the `myvar` context variable
- print temporary variable (1)

`{{ myvar }}` -> **output : 100**

As `myvar` is assigned to a local variable, use it.

#### Conclusion

If you need a local counter use @marcanuy solution.

If you need a global counter use `{% increment myvar %}` tag and do not rely on `{{ myvar }}` to print its value, because you're not sure that a local `myvar` is assigned/declared.

Comment: Great explanation!