# Can I insert a number from file in markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, document

When writing a manuscript in Rmd, I could make the numbers inside the paper dynamic. Eg. `r number`. This is great, when reporting basic stats in a paper, that are subject to change as new material is added.

Could I do something similar in simple github flavored markdown or when converting markdown to a pdf via latex, that would get the right numbers from file when compiling a document? E.g. I could write a file with all the relevant numbers, one per row, and have the markdown then read and present these numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub MarkDown: Are Macros and Variables possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580042/github-markdown-are-macros-and-variables-possible)